# skip first line in mysql export to .txt file in linux

Tags: mysql, linux

I want to make a sitemap for google. the fastest way to do it (i think) is exporting the query directly to a txt file with a linux command. I do it like this

```
$ mysql  -pMyPassword -e "SELECT concat('http:/mysitecom/',id,'/',urlPart1,'/',urlPart2,'/') as url FROM products LIMIT 50000" > /home/file.xml
```

the problem is google says there has to be nothing but urls in the txt file, and my first line is "url" which is the resulting column name, typical for CSV file. How can i skip it?

Comment: You could try to make usage of awk or sed with some regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Piping it to `tail` should work

```
mysql  -pMyPassword -e "SELECT concat('http:/mysitecom/',id,'/',urlPart1,'/',urlPart2,'/') as url FROM products LIMIT 50000" | tail -n +2 > /home/file.xml
```

Do remember that you'll have to do this each time that table is updated. Depending on the implementation of your site I'd imagine that it wouldn't be too complex to write a query and output the list at an endpoint such as `domain.com/sitemap` - what language are you using?

### Using PHP

Pretty simple:

```
// do your regular database connection where $db = mysqli_connect(...);

$resource = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT concat('http:/mysitecom/',id,'/',urlPart1,'/',urlPart2,'/') as url FROM products");

while ($arr=mysqli_fetch_row($resource)){
    $urls[]=$arr[0];
}

header('Content-type: text/plain');
foreach ($urls as $url){
    echo $url.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Should work but haven't tested it! (esp. the header, that's off the top of my head)

Comment: Well yes; it's not by any means the regular way of doing it, but it's the quickest adaptation of the current suggestion - if we knew the language the site was written in it would be trivial to write the query into a dynamic page too.

Comment: I'm using php, but I want to avoid using it for such a heavy duty

Comment: Have made up some PHP code that should achieve the same effect; doesn;t include DB connection as I'm guessing you already have some code to get  a database object.